# FluentAssertions: ShouldBeEquivalentTo method still invokes Object.Equals()?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a class, let's call it `Foo`, that is a value type and hence overrides the `Equals`/`GetHashCode()` methods. In a separate test fixture, I want to assert that all the properties on Foo have been set properly, not just the properties used for equality. For this reason, my test assertion specifically uses the `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` method, which the documentation suggests will consider two objects to be equivalent if "both object graphs have equally named properties with the same value, irrespective of the type of those objects."

However, it appears that `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` invokes `Foo.Equals` method, gets a true result and then proceeds to short-circuit the reflection based property matching that `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` promises.

Is this expected behavior?  If so, in inspecting the FA source, I saw no easy way to alter this behavior (`IEquivalencyStep` is declared internal).  Are there any other ways to around this?

Edit:
Dennis: Yes, the two objects I'm comparing are of the same type.  To summarize, I have overridden `Equals`  on class Foo, but do not want FA to use this notion of equality for my unit tests.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do. Is that object similar to the one you're invoking ShouldBeEquivalentTo() on?

Comment: For future reference, Dennis addressed this issue here: http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/discussions/428950, said that the behavior was changed in 2.1

Comment: Argaz, if you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot alter behavior of this function, it assumes that if you override `Equals` - than you want comparison to be the same way. You can try the following function:

```
dto.ShouldHave().SharedProperties().EqualTo(foo);
```

Or you can implement in Foo class `NativeEquals` method which will be calling `base.Equals()` , and then use this method explicitly for comparison, it will work great for value types.

Comment: Won't work, because SharedProperties() internally uses the same engine as ShouldBeEquivalentTo() does. I know, because I've designed it...